# window.scrollTo triggers a view refresh

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im using `window.scrollTo(0, some_value)` on a form in a Backbone app. Each time the user selects a new input, it scroll a little. If I select the inputs, slowly, it works fine. But if I quickly select an input one after another, the whole view gets refreshed. Any ideas why?

Comment: It sounds like you have something bound to the `scroll` event.

Comment: justed edited question. i havent bound to scroll event

Comment: If you post your url or create a jsfiddle I'll take a look.